# Creating an IE Toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, toolbar

Where can I find information on adding a toolbar to IE like "Snagit" and other tools does?

What I am basically trying to do is add a button, such that when clicked my tool will be launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer: [MSDN: Adding Toolbar Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588.aspx)

For more, do you have any details on what exactly you're trying to do, the language/environment e.g. C++/MFC/ATL/.NET?

Comment: VB.NET or C#. I am trying to create a small screen capture screen, but will allow the user to persist the capture to database with additional info.

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588(VS.85).aspx) will walk you through adding a single toolbar button to the IE toolbar.  You can make your target extension be some JScript or a COM object.

Answer (score 2):

www.besttoolbars.net has a platfrom to create IE and Firefox toolbars. They give source code for the final toolbar so that you can have a starting point of your customizations.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://cgeers.wordpress.com/2008/02/16/internet-explorer-toolbar/) gives a great detailed walkthrough of how to create an IE toolbar using Visual Studio.